# Rails - joining active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to follow through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

I have a class, ImageCollection, that has a status which can be 'active'. This class belongs to one Image, which has an attribute called 'workflow_state'.

I have the following that works but takes a few seconds to execute:

```
def self.published
  where(status: STATUS_ACTIVE).select { |x| x.image.workflow_state == Publishable::Meta.published_key }
end
```

The following does not work:

```
scope :published, lambda {
  where(status: STATUS_ACTIVE).joins(:image).where(
    'image.workflow_state = ?', Publishable::Meta.published_key
  )
}
```

And returns:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'image.workflow_state' in 'where clause': SELECT  `image_containers`.* FROM `image_containers` INNER JOIN `images` ON `images`.`id` = `image_containers`.`image_id` WHERE `image_containers`.`status` = 'active' AND (image.workflow_state = 'published') ORDER BY `image.containers`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I'm confused as the image table has a workflow_state

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you - if you post that as an answer I'll accept it when it lets me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using plain sql you should use pluralize table names.

Change: `image.workflow_state` to `images.workflow_state`

Answer (score 2):

> I have the following that works but takes a few seconds to execute:

The query from `self.published` method fetches all record with `status: STATUS_ACTIVE`, and then scans the resulting array, fetching those ones which have given `image.workflow_state`. So it fetches results which will be thrown away with `select`, which is a waste of resources. What is worse, for every row it creates an ActiveRecord object and makes an additional request to the database to fetch its `image` association. It's notorious [N + 1 pattern problem](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

To fix it you need to rewrite your query as

```
  joins(:image).where(status: STATUS_ACTIVE, images: { workflow_state: Publishable::Meta.published_key } )
```

Comment: I didn't realise it could be written as that - have used the other answer but thanks for the info! :)